# How can I resolve duplicate content issue for my 2 pages

Tags: duplicate-content

Here is scenarios :

URL 1 : http://www.example.com/topics

URL 2 : http://www.example.com

Some of top topic we are displaying in home page[URL 2] as well and that is necessary for us.

Google consider it as duplicate content. How can I resolve this issue.

I know that it can be resolve by assign `rel=canonical`but which URL from 2 I should declare as canonical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical: You can use this if the same page content can be viewed using multiple URLs.

Let's say:

Link 1: example.com/page1/

Link 2: example.com/info-page/

Let's say if above 2 pages would have same content then you an assign canonical to let Google know about preferred URL. Let's say to keep Link 1 as preferred URL then in Link 2 canonical can be assigned.

If you got a portion of content in home page and topics page which are similar then you can display bit less text one one page and detailed content on the dedicated page. Canonical may not work in this scenario.

Duplicate: Unless you got too much content which is similar it may not be treated as duplicate content. So, if you create a balance you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Now here when I analyzed in depth I got to know that search engine consider pages as duplicate content even if it is like *Home page has footer menu and one menu item there called Privacy policy* & **There is separate privacy policy page**. What should I do here? Add home page as canonical link for privacy policy page?

Comment: Privacy Policy, T&C are generally similar content in most of the websites. Focus on quality content for main pages, these pages shouldn't impact much. If you are concerned then you may like to keep these pages as an image. I wouldn't worry much about it.